# How can I restrict the number of records (reviews) added by a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I go about restricting the number of reviews a user can write for a venue to just one?

I would also like a flash message prompt if they try to review a venue twice.

I'm not too sure what code I should to include in my question but heres the create review method:

**Review controller**

```
def create
  @review = current_user.reviews.create!(params[:review])
  @review.venue = @venue
  if @review.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Thank you for reviewing this venue!'
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to venue_path(@venue) }
      format.js
    end
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

**edit**

I've added this helper method into the venues controller:

```
  def reviewed?
    if current_user.reviews.for_venue(@venue).empty?
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

and wrapped my form in:

```
<% if reviewed? %>
  form
<% end %>
```

but this just returns undefined method `reviews' for VenuesController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you could prevent the user from reviewing the venue in the first place. In your view(or create a helper) do a check if the venue was already reviewed by the user(many ways to do this). If it was, don't show the review form. Easy. If you're pretty OC, that's when you check in the controller.

Comment: thanks for tha answer I've been mulling over this for a bit and am a bit stuck could you have a look at my edit? what am I missing?

Comment: whats in your for_venue(@venue) method?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a before_validation callback, so that you can check if the venue has been already reviewed by the user. You can include the venue in the create line:

```
current_user.reviews.create!({:venue_id => @venue.id}.merge(params[:review]))
```

And for the validation, use something like this:

```
before_validation :check_if_already_reviewed

def check_if_already_reviewed
  if (check if already reviewed)
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end
```